# Should I use polite speech to animals?

Tags: formal

When talking to people in Korean, there are social rules (heirarchy, age, general politeness) that determine whether I should use formal speech like 해요 or 합니다. But what about if I'm talking to animals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's usually *weird* to use polite speech or honorifics to pets or animals, unless doing so sarcastically or ironically (or just to sound cute).

General rule of thumb: just use 반말 to animals.

Comment: When speaking to a horse, speak in half-horse =)